# Use dynamic SASS function names inside a loop

Tags: css, sass

I am creating some utility classes via a loop but wan't to use the functions that already exist.

I have some functions that I use within other CSS:

```
@function size-1() {
    @return  #{ ( 8 / 16 ) }rem;
}
@function size-2() {
    @return #{ ( 16 / 16 ) }rem;
}
@function size-3() {
    @return #{ ( 24 / 16 ) }rem;
}
@function size-4() {
    @return #{ ( 32 / 16 ) }rem;
}
```

But I also created a loop so that I have classes to use in the markup too:

```
@for $i from 1 through 18 {
    .mt-#{$i} {
        margin-top: size-$i();
    }
}
```

I have tried (above) to dynamically call the function but it only outputs text of 'size-1' if I do it dynamically. If I use the direct function name e.g.:

```
margin-top: size-1();
```

Then it correctly works. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function [call](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#call) to call yours:

```
@function size-1() {
    @return  #{ ( 8 / 16 ) }rem;
}
@function size-2() {
    @return #{ ( 16 / 16 ) }rem;
}
@function size-3() {
    @return #{ ( 24 / 16 ) }rem;
}
@function size-4() {
    @return #{ ( 32 / 16 ) }rem;
}

...

@for $i from 1 through 18 {
    .mt-#{$i} {
        margin-top: call(size- + $i);
    }
}
```

(Tested in: https://www.sassmeister.com/ )

EDIT: Another way with less functions:

```
@function size($num) {
    @return  #{ ( $num/2) }rem;
}

@for $i from 1 through 18 {
    .mt-#{$i} {
        margin-top: size($i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. First time testing out a mixture of utility class styles and the aim of all the functions was to limit other developers to a set amount of options for margins etc. However, doing this again I would use a generic size function that mapped to an allowed set of sizes and threw an error if not in the list.